# how to resolve error in installing pycsv in python3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pyinstaller

as I'm doing this code and need the CSV library to execute this.

```
import csv

class CsvWordReplacer(WordReplacer):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        word_map = {}
        for line in csv.reader(open(fname)):
            word, syn = line
            word_map[word] = syn
            super(CsvWordReplacer, self).__init__(word_map)
replacer = CsvWordReplacer('synonyms.csv')
a=replacer.replace('bday')
```

while installing the library in *Python 3.7* using *pyserial3.2* by giving the command in cmd(administrator) as:

```
pip install --user pycsv
```

I found the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        long_description=io.open("history.md", encoding='utf8').read(),
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'history.md'
```

if anyone could help me out that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need install the `csv` library module. It is part of the standard library. Uninstall `pycsv` (which, according to its own documentation on PyPI, does not support Python 3, and was last updated over 3 years ago) and just use `csv`.

Comment: i use csv first but found this error: Collecting csv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for csv

Comment: That is because you *tried to install* `csv`. Don't do that. It is part of the standard library, which means it is installed already. Just import it in your program.

Comment: as above given code i use to import csv but also find error:            FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'synonyms.csv'

Comment: That is nothing to do with the installation of `csv`. If that did not work you would get an `ImportError`. But it is working. Your problem is you are calling `CsvWordReplacer()` and passing it the name of a `.csv` file (`synonyms.csv`) that does not exist, or that the interpreter cannot find because it is looking for it somewhere other than you expect. Put the full path to the file in the call.